check that template arguments corresponds to function pointer
How can I accomplish this? Currently getting the following compilation error
error: member pointer refers into non-class type 'Test *'
    6 |     if constexpr (std::is_same<MethodT, void (ObjectT::*)(int)>::value)

#include <type_traits>

template<typename MethodT, typename ObjectT>
void RegisterCallback(MethodT method, ObjectT object)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same<MethodT, void (ObjectT::*)(int)>::value)
   {
    // do something
   }
   if constexpr (std::is_same<MethodT, void (ObjectT::*)(int, float)>::value)
   {
    // do something else
   }
}

int main()
{
   struct Test
   {
    void HandleCallbackWithInt(int)
    {}

    void HandleCallbackWithIntFloat(int, float)
    {}

   } receiver;

   RegisterCallback(&Test::HandleCallbackWithInt, &receiver);

   return 0;
}


When you pass &receiver to ObjectT object, the ObjectT gets deduced as Test* and ObjectT::* is invalid for a pointer type ObjectT. You might want
template<typename MethodT, typename ObjectT>
void RegisterCallback(MethodT method, ObjectT* object)
// ------------------------------------------^

and ObjectT would get deduced as Test.

Thanks, I am not sure how I missed that :)
